# Use Another Procedure or Use 2 Lines of Query

Tags: mysql

I have a working procedure named "user_create" that checks for some conditions, creates a row and outputs the row id. Im planning to use this procedure at PHP side with this query:

```
CALL user_create('name', 'pass123', @status);
SELECT @status;
```

Is it better to use this way. Or should I create another procedure that just calls "user_create" and selects its output. That way I can just use a single CALL at the PHP end to get the status.

Comment: Do not return the result in the variable. Perform SELECT as the most last statement of your SP. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=690e9e02ad812946225b8be04b727334

Comment: I forgot to say. There are other procedures that calls "user_create" and they have SELECT statements. Therefore I cant use SELECT in "user_create".

Comment: If so then simply assign needed value into user-defined (not local!) variable with pre-defined name in nested SP and use it in outer SP.